# Javascript keyCode

Tags: javascript, debugging, keycode, fromcharcode

i have a problem with keyCode in javascript i used this exact code from tutorial

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", keypressed);

function keypressed(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 46){
        alert("key pressed")
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work for me (it works in the tutorial), however when i tried to use enter which is 13 and space which is 32 both work, but not a-z or numbers or anything else, any idea why? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you checking for the [right keycodes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)?  (46 is the code for "delete", though some keyboards will send "backspace" (keycode 8) instead...)  It may be better to use [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) which is a little bit more standardized.

Comment: Yes I'm aware thats the del button, i was testing all the buttons, yes i was aware of a scenario like you mentioned, i even did another test exercise to make sure that the input was correct, i printed on the browser what ever the input was so if i press delete it would print 46 with alert message and it all works.. but i cant see why it doesnt work with the original example.. thanks for the input i will try out the event.which

Comment: In that case I'm unclear on what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Alas, your tutoral is out of date.

Fortunately, MDN is a good source for accurate information on javsacript and for keyCode it says, “[keyCode is deprecated, don't use it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)”

Instead, use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) for keystrokes or `code` for keyboard codes:

```
function keypressed(event){
    if(event.key=== "."){
        alert("key pressed")
    }
}
```

Note, with event.key you use the literal character, not the code: " " instead of 32.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it works but only when i use "." i tried "32" for instance but no luck, i will look into the document thanks.

Comment: No, you don't want "32" you want " ".

Comment: Play with it by opening the js console in your browser on this page, and type as one line:  `document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){ console.log(e.code, e.key); if(e.key==window.myKey)alert(e.key)});`
Then type `myKey=" "`. Then type in the document, e,g, by adding a comment.